# OpenNLP NameFinder is not working

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am new to OpenNLP and following it's documentation for NameFinder. I have downloaded OpenNLP version 1.7.2 and downloaded en-ner-person.bin model from OpenNLP project webpage. Here is my example class:

```
public class OpenNLPExamples {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputFileName = "en-ner-person.bin";
        String[] inputString = new String[]{"mike", "and", "smiths", "are", "good", "friends."};
        NameFinderME model=null;
        InputStream modelFile=null;
        TokenNameFinderModel modelStream=null;

        try {
            modelFile = new FileInputStream("/Users/saurabh/Desktop/en-ner-person.bin");
            modelStream = new TokenNameFinderModel(modelFile);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                modelFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        model = new NameFinderME(modelStream);
        Span spans[] = model.find(inputString);
        System.out.println("span length: " + spans.length);

        for(Span span: spans) {
            System.out.println(span.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput for the given code is empty. I printed spans lenght too, it is zero. I used command line tool too but no good luck. Can any one tell me am I making any mistake here or problem is with trained model?

Comment: Try changing "mike" to "Mike" ;) Haven't verified this with the model available from opennlp (but with one I trained myself), but that could get you a match. Orthographic features (like uppercase characters) are usually important for these maxent-models, so using them as you would in normal text increases your chances of recognising stuff. (I tried it with my model and your code, and the code itself looks fine/worked as expected)